# Extract text from a file using RegEx

Tags: php, regex

I have a text file which has the follwing data,

`dup dx mul x0 add exch dup dy mul y0 add exch dr mul r0 add
 a1 a2 arcn
 dup dx mul x0 add exch dup dy mul y0 add exch dr mul r0 add
 a2 a1 arcn h
 dup dx mul x0 add exch dup dy mul y0 add exch dr mul r0 add
 a1 a2 arc
 dup dx mul x0 add exch dup dy mul y0 add exch dr mul r0 add
 a2 a1 arc h f
%%EndResource
The text i want to grap
showpage`

So i want all the text in between `%%EndResource` and `showpage`.

Any help will be appreciated ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex

```
/%%EndResource(.*)showpage/g
```

To get the value between this, use `$1`

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
/(?<=%%EndResource).*?(?=showpage)/s
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?308bo)

`(?<=%%EndResource)` is a look behind assertion, it ensures that "%%EndResource" is before the part you want to get.

`(?=showpage)` is a look ahead assertion, it ensures that "%%EndResource" is following the part you want to get.

`.` is matching any character (including linebreaks becasue of the `s` modifier at the end)

`*?` matches any amount of characters and the empty string(!), but as less as possible (because of the `?`)

Answer (score 0):

No regex is required here.

```
$start = strpos($the_string, "%%EndResource") + count("%%EndResource");
$end = strpos($the_string, "showpage")

$result = substr($the_string, $start, $end - $start);
```

Eventually add `trim()` if you want to loose the spaces.

Answer (score 0):

The following regex will capture what you need in a group which you can then later access.

The regex is this:

`%%EndResource(.*?)showpage`

You can see how you can access the data in a regex group using [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/php.html) tutorial.